# How to put multiple components/templates on the same view and choose which one to display based on dropdownlist item using Angular2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC app.
My current task is to update one of the views with templates based on selected dropdownlist item.
The whole view is simply kendo grid. When you select an item on choose either add new or edit existing, a pop up windows appears.
There is a dropdownlist on the top of that window and all I need to do is to display different template (of fields to populate) based on selected dropdownlist item.

I want to use angular 2 for that. I'm not sure whether this can be achieved using routing, as I wouldn't need angular for the other views in the app.

So I was thinking about having multiple component, each would point to different html template. Based on the selected dropdownlist item, I would simply display that component and fetch the data (for edits)

Do you think this approach would work? I'm wondering how I can place multiple component in the same view and bind the display style to the selected dropdownlist item?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this functionality in different ways as below.

- Dynamic component loading by DynamicModule bind based on your component selector.

  https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d
- Using `<dynamic-html [content]="yourContent"></dynamic-html>`.

  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic
- By using IF Statement as below.

  ```
  <div [ngSwitch]="true">
      <div *ngSwitchCase="componentTag=='about'">
          <about></about>
      </div>
      <div *ngSwitchCase="componentTag=='qaDashboard'">
          <qaDashboard"></qaDashboard>
      </div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'll give it a try and see how it works out for me.

Comment: if you have less component then last option is best in performance

Comment: In the last option, how do I render the templates for "about", "qaDashboard" and other components? I would put them inside the parent component, but I'm just not sure how they would be rendered?

Comment: Based on the selected dropdownlist value, in value you bind component selector and in last option "componentTag" is a selector of component.